# how to use puppeteer to goto web page then press Control P to print the page?

Tags: puppeteer

How to press control + P on a web page that is automated by puppeteer?

This code loads the web page.  But using `await page.keyboard.down('Control')` to press the  Control key has no effect.

```
(async () =>
{
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto(`https://google.com`);

  await page.waitForSelector('input'); 
  await page.focus("input");

 // this works
  await page.keyboard.down('Shift');
  await page.keyboard.press('KeyP');
  await page.keyboard.up('Shift');

// this has no effect.
  await page.keyboard.down('Control');
  await page.keyboard.press('KeyP');
  await page.keyboard.up('Control');

})();
```

What I would like to do is navigate to a PDF file. Have the browser open the PDF. Then press Control P and automate the print dialog to the extent that the code selects the printer to print to and presses the Enter key.

Comment: I have a PDF file. ( a packing list ). When we close an order in the warehouse I want to print the packing list to the printer at the packing station. When I send the PDF direct to port 9100 of the printer it does not print correctly. But when I open the PDF in the browser and print from there, it does.  So I want to automate the browser to print the PDF.

Comment: I am not sure about selectingg printer and pressing Enter, but you can try `await page.evaluate(() => { window.print(); });` to open the dialog.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

running puppeteer in `kiosk` mode enables the `window.print( )` dialog to be automatically responded to.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () =>
{
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch(
    {
      headless: false, 
      "args": [ "--kiosk-printing" ]
    });

  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto(`file:///C:/Users/srich/Downloads/packing-list.pdf`);

  await page.evaluate(() => { window.print(); });
  await page.waitForTimeout(2000) ;

  await browser.close( ) ;
})();
```

Comment: When I use `--kiosk-printing` I am unable to change my file name. Do you have any solution for this? I am actually using this to save as pdf instead of print, so I don't have any printer connected.